# Excel Memory pumps to 2,800 mb/s when closing

Tags: excel, excel-addins

The steady state of the file is at 430mb/s. Memory doesnt change much after running macros as well as after saving the file, but when I close the file the memory shoots to 2800ish mb/s and the file just about crashes before closing.  I get the "Not Responding" at the top.

Whats the deal?  Could it be from a 3rd party add-in?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, not in a particular order:

- disable add-ins 1 by 1 to isolate problematic plugins.
- run without macros.
- check if you have anything running the Workbook.BeforeClose event